# Encoding of special characters

Tags: python, pandas, csv, encoding, xlsx

I have a.xlsx and I have done some operations on it, and when I'm exporting it to a.csv format (to reduce time) using df.to_csv(output.csv, encoding='utf -l6-le') there is a special character '–' between texts in input file(.xlsx) column but on the output file(.csv), but it changes it to ''.

I have used other encodings, utf-8 and utf-32, as well, but they didn't work as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

encoding type 'Windows-1252' is used for special characters.

Wiki for Windows-1252 is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)